# Asynchronous execution of javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, time-complexity

I am studying javascript and json but I've some problems: I have a script that works with json but the performances of what I wrote aren't that good. The code works only if I do a debug step by step with firebug or other tools and that makes me think that the execution of the code (or a part of it ... the one that creates the table as you'll see) requires too much time so the browser stops it.

The code is:

```
var arrayCarte = [];
var arrayEntita = [];
var arraycardbyuser = [];

function displayArrayCards() {
var richiestaEntity = new XMLHttpRequest();

richiestaEntity.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(richiestaEntity.readyState == 4) {
        var objectentityjson = {};
        objectentityjson = JSON.parse(richiestaEntity.responseText);

        arrayEntita = objectentityjson.cards;
    }
}
richiestaEntity.open("GET", "danielericerca.json", true);
richiestaEntity.send(null);

for(i = 0; i < arrayEntita.length; i++) {

    var vanityurla = arrayEntita[i].vanity_urls[0] + ".json";
    var urlrichiesta = "http://m.airpim.com/public/vurl/";

    var richiestaCards = new XMLHttpRequest();
    richiestaCards.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(richiestaCards.readyState == 4) {
            var objectcardjson = {};
            objectcardjson = JSON.parse(richiestaCards.responseText);


            for(j = 0; j < objectcardjson.cards.length; j++)
            arrayCarte[j] = objectcardjson.cards[j].__guid__; //vettore che contiene i guid delle card

            arraycardbyuser[i] = arrayCarte;

            arrayCarte = [];
        }
    }
    richiestaCards.open("GET", vanityurla, true);
    richiestaCards.send(null);
}





var wrapper = document.getElementById('contenitoro');

wrapper.innerHTML = "";

var userTable = document.createElement('table');

for(u = 0; u < arrayEntita.length; u++) {
    var userTr = document.createElement('tr');

    var userTdcard = document.createElement('td');
    var userTdinfo = document.createElement('td');

    var br = document.createElement('br');

    for(c = 0; c < arraycardbyuser[u].length; c++) {
        var cardImg = document.createElement('img');
        cardImg.src = "http://www.airpim.com/png/public/card/" + arraycardbyuser[u][c] + "?width=292";
        cardImg.id = "immaginecard";
        userTdcard.appendChild(br);
        userTdcard.appendChild(cardImg);

    }

    var userdivNome = document.createElement('div');
    userdivNome.id = "diverso";
    userTdinfo.appendChild(userdivNome);

    var userdivVanity = document.createElement('div');
    userdivVanity.id = "diverso";
    userTdinfo.appendChild(userdivVanity);

    var nome = "Nome: ";
    var vanityurl = "Vanity Url: ";
    userdivNome.innerHTML = nome + arrayEntita[u].__title__;
    userdivVanity.innerHTML = vanityurl + arrayEntita[u].vanity_urls[0];

    userTr.appendChild(userTdcard);
    userTr.appendChild(userTdinfo);
    userTable.appendChild(userTr);
}

wrapper.appendChild(userTable);
}
```

The problem is that the code that should make the table doesn't wait for the complete execution of the code that works with the json files. How can I fix it? I would prefer,if possible, to solve that problem with something easy, without jquery and callbacks (I am a beginner).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to move som code around to make that work.  at first, split it up in some functions, then it is easier to work with. I dont know if it works, but the idea is that first it loads the arrayEntita. When that is done, it fills the other 2 arrays. And when the last array has been filled, it builds the table.

```
 var arrayCarte = [];
 var arrayEntita = [];
 var arraycardbyuser = [];
 function displayArrayCards() {
    var richiestaEntity = new XMLHttpRequest();
        richiestaEntity.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (richiestaEntity.readyState == 4) {
             var objectentityjson = {};
             objectentityjson = JSON.parse(richiestaEntity.responseText);

              arrayEntita = objectentityjson.cards;
              BuildArrayEntita();
            }
        }
        richiestaEntity.open("GET", "danielericerca.json", true);
        richiestaEntity.send(null);
    }

    function BuildArrayEntita() {
        for (i = 0; i < arrayEntita.length; i++) {

            var vanityurla = arrayEntita[i].vanity_urls[0] + ".json";
            var urlrichiesta = "http://m.airpim.com/public/vurl/";

            var richiestaCards = new XMLHttpRequest();
            richiestaCards.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (richiestaCards.readyState == 4) {
                    var objectcardjson = {};
                    objectcardjson = JSON.parse(richiestaCards.responseText);


                    for (j = 0; j < objectcardjson.cards.length; j++)
                        arrayCarte[j] = objectcardjson.cards[j].__guid__; //vettore che contiene i guid delle card

                    arraycardbyuser[i] = arrayCarte;

                    arrayCarte = [];
                    //If it is the last call to populate arraycardbyuser, build the table:
                    if (i + 1 == arrayEntita.length)
                        BuildTable();
                }
            }
            richiestaCards.open("GET", vanityurla, true);
            richiestaCards.send(null);
        }
    }



    function BuildTable() {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('contenitoro');

        wrapper.innerHTML = "";

        var userTable = document.createElement('table');

        for (u = 0; u < arrayEntita.length; u++) {
            var userTr = document.createElement('tr');

            var userTdcard = document.createElement('td');
            var userTdinfo = document.createElement('td');

            var br = document.createElement('br');

            for (c = 0; c < arraycardbyuser[u].length; c++) {
                var cardImg = document.createElement('img');
                cardImg.src = "http://www.airpim.com/png/public/card/" + arraycardbyuser[u][c] + "?width=292";
                cardImg.id = "immaginecard";
                userTdcard.appendChild(br);
                userTdcard.appendChild(cardImg);

            }

            var userdivNome = document.createElement('div');
            userdivNome.id = "diverso";
            userTdinfo.appendChild(userdivNome);

            var userdivVanity = document.createElement('div');
            userdivVanity.id = "diverso";
            userTdinfo.appendChild(userdivVanity);

            var nome = "Nome: ";
            var vanityurl = "Vanity Url: ";
            userdivNome.innerHTML = nome + arrayEntita[u].__title__;
            userdivVanity.innerHTML = vanityurl + arrayEntita[u].vanity_urls[0];

            userTr.appendChild(userTdcard);
            userTr.appendChild(userTdinfo);
            userTable.appendChild(userTr);
        }

        wrapper.appendChild(userTable);
    }
```

i dont know if this check:

```
if (i + 1 == arrayEntita.length)
    BuildTable();
```

but else you have to check if alle responseses have returned before executing buildtable();

Comment: I'm trying but if I call BuildArrayEntita from displayArrayCards (like you did) it doesn't work (that's why I didn't use different functions and I put all the code in one method).

Comment: What doesnt work? have you tried to inspect your objectentityjson.cards to make sure it contains what you expect it to contain. try putting in console.log("--unique text--"); in the start of each method (and in the onreadystatechange functions). Then you can see the order of execution.

Comment: I've some alerts here and there to understand what's going on but I can't see one of them.

Comment: At the first look seems that the button doesn't recall the function

<input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="displayArrayCards();" />

Comment: i think console.log is better, because alert pauses the code and leaves more time for the the server call to finish, where console.log adds the message to the log and continues execution.

Comment: your javascript might have some error, have you checked your browsers console?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX requests are asynchronous. They arrive at an unknown period during execution and JavaScript does not wait for the server to reply before proceeding. There is synchronous XHR but it's not for ideal use. You'd lose the whole idea of AJAX if you do so.

What is usually done is to pass in a "callback" - a function that is executed sometime later, depending on when you want it executed. In your case, you want the table to be generated after you receive the data:

```
function getData(callback){
    //AJAX setup
    var richiestaEntity = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //listen for readystatechange
    richiestaEntity.onreadystatechange = function() {

        //listen for state 4 and ok status (200)
        if (richiestaEntity.readyState === 4 && richiestaEntity.status === 200) {

            //execute callback when data is received passing it
            //what "this" is in the callback function, as well as
            //the returned data
            callback.call(this,richiestaEntity.responseText);
        }
    }
    richiestaEntity.open("GET", "danielericerca.json"); //third parameter defaults to true
    richiestaEntity.send();
}

function displayArrayCards() {

    //this function passed to getData will be executed
    //when data arrives
    getData(function(returnedData){

        //put here what you want to execute when getData receives the data
        //"returnedData" variable inside this function is the JSON returned

    });
}
```

Comment: The code that works on the second json works only if the work with the first one is completed. So I should work on the second json too and then do the table.
I should put the execution of the second request inside the if of function getData(callback)?

Comment: @user1453638 you'd have to do another `getData` within the first `getData` if it relies on the first set of fetched data. on the other hand, you might need to restructure your data. Multiple AJAX calls isn't ideal also. If possible, do it in one call.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have made the ajax call, put all of the rest of the code inside the readystatechange function. This way, it will execute everything in order.

**Edit:** @Dappergoat has explained it better than I can.